# Letting User Draw On a Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if it's possible to allow a user to draw a line from Point A to point B on a Google map?

If so, how is this usually done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Polylines and specify two points or more using gooogle.maps.LatLng.  Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/FCXsX/):

```
  //create points on the Polylines
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];

  //create the Polyline and feed it points with stroke styling
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  //set the polylines on the map
  flightPath.setMap(map);
```

To be much more detail as others suggests, the coodinates can be either entered by user either by a click event to place markers as points on the map and then supply the markers coodinates as points for the polylines or you can also create a form where the users can manually enter their address or their lat lng as points to draw the points, but the detail way of drawing the polylines is similar to the above example except Lat Lng are statically coded on the demo.

Comment: He wants the user to be able to draw on the map...this just displays two points statically coded.

Comment: @Achilles there u go i've added in depth suggestion

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as an answer; it doesn't address the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation on [polylines](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines). You just need to add an 'click' event on the map and handle the drawing of the lines.

Answer (score 2):

They have sample code which allows you to do this(to see the code simply click view source):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex.html

1. Wire an onclick event to your map.
2. Add a point to your polyline(the line the use is drawing) by looking at the `event.LatLng` object to get the Latitude and Longitude.
3. When the user clicks again the polyline will automatically update the rendering when the new point has been pushed onto the array it renders from.

Comment: This is a good example, but my requirement is different.  I forgot to mention that I need users to draw curved lines - not necessarily straight lines.  Is it possible to let users draw curved lines?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to be posting the solution on this test page:
http://www.comehike.com/draggable_marker.php

At the time of this answer, the solution is not there, but hopefully very soon I will get this working.

Comment: let me know if you help =D.  Also, there's a similar question here that i answered earlier today hopefully it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338279/overlay-in-google-maps/5339832#5339832

Comment: Thank you - I am still thinking about how to let people draw because since they are going to be making trails, the lines are naturally curvy and not a grid like streets would be.  This is something I am considering and researching before I jump in.  By the way, your help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: http://www.comehike.com/draggable_marker.php is a pretty cool place, too.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Check out [MapMyRun.com](http://www.mapmyrun.com/routes/create/) for a great example of a use case.

Comment: Is there a particular page there which might be good?  I tried to map my run there, but it was so cluttered with controls that I couldn't do it and didn't get any source examples. :(

Comment: That is a very feature-rich web app you're trying to reverse engineer. I meant it only as an example that something like it can be done. But check out this early beta from Genadnik: http://www.comehike.com/draggable_marker.php (I just tested it.) It may give you some ideas on how to get started.