# Overlay in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem with overlays in google maps.

the problem is iam using latitude and longitude from the database to display overlay
but its not showing the overlay

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
            <%
                Connection connection = null;
                boolean foundResults = false;
                ResultSet set = null;
                Statement statement = null;         
                String lat=null;
                String lng=null;
            %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;
function initialize()
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9, 72.8);   
    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 11,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);   
    see();
    }
    function see()
    {
        <%
                    int count=0;
                    try 
                    {
                        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","postgres", "password");
                        statement = connection.createStatement();
                        set = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(lat) from latng");
                        while(set.next())
                        {
                            count = set.getInt(1);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
            %>
        var locations = new Array(<%= count%>);
        for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            locations[i] = new Array(<%= count%>);
        }
        <%
            int i=0;
            try
            {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres","postgres", "password");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                set = statement.executeQuery("SELECT lat, lng FROM latng");
                while(set.next())
                {
                    lat=set.getString(1);
                    lng=set.getString(2);
        %>
                    locations[<%= i %>][0]=<%= lat%>;
                    locations[<%= i %>][1]=<%= lng%>;   
                    <%
                        i++;
                }
                    %>
                    var i;
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var marker;
                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
                    {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0],locations[i][1]),map: map});

                            var flightPlanCoordinates=[new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0],locations[i][1])];
                            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                                                                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                                                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                                                    strokeWeight: 2
                                                                });
                            flightPath.setMap(map);
                    }
        <%

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        %>
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width=100%; height:80%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks please some one help me...............

Comment: are you getting the data from the database correctly?

Comment: The code is not working with static values, I checked.

Comment: @M'vy when you say not working which part of it is not working?  what does firebug or chrome developer tool says?

Comment: @kjy112 in fact I think the values I used for the static case were out of the scope. Look at my proposition just down there. I got the map with 3 points on it. (static values of course)

Comment: @M'vy yes, but i am not sure how he wants to overlay the map? lines between points?

Comment: That's what I asked, now waiting for update.

Comment: @M'vy it seems like that's what he attempts to do.  if that's the case i have an answer for it.  i'll go ahead and post it.

Comment: Thanks kjy112 and M'vy for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/c9GTK/):

First we create a global variable to hold our polyline points:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [];  //global array to track our Lat Lng needed to plot the polyline
```

The issue you have is that you aren't feeding the polyline more than one Lat Lng.  So, basically, it's not drawing a polyline, because it only has one Lat Lng to create it.  You need more than one Lat Lng to create a line of some sort.  Thus, we created a global array called `flightPlanCoordinates` to track the Lat Lng of the polyline, and pushes the locations Lat Lng to it with in the for loop.  After the for loop is over we then create the polyline overlay and set it with the current map:

```
function see() {
    var locations = new Array(3); //(<%= count%>);
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        locations[i] = new Array(2); //This one is wrong!! (<%= count%>);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        locations[i][0] = 18.9 + i / 100;
        locations[i][1] = 72.8 + i / 100;
    }

    var i;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map
        });

        //pushing Lat Lng to use to create polyline
        flightPlanCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]));
    }

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Further note, your info window doesn't really have anything to show for.  There's no click event associate w/ marker to open it.

Comment: Thanks kjy112 its working perfectly what i want but what i want is getting latitude and longitude fron database ...... this isnt working ..... can u help me.......

Comment: i tried it and some changes..... its working even with the database...... Thnaks kjy112.....can u explain me how did u do that......i saw u have taken an flightPlanCoordinates[] as array and used a push function.......can u explain me what have u done.........please kjy112

Comment: The way you originally feed your polyline wasn't working because you simply feed only one point to it and attempt to create the line.  Polyline needs multiple points for creation.  So, basically i created a global array and feed it more than one point to create your polyline.  `Please accept/up vote answer to your questions.  So, people will be more willing to help you in the future.`

Comment: Hai kjy112 i got a new problem can u help me please follow the link httP://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457937/google-maps-polyline

Answer (score 2):

Ok, not a full answer for the moment but I got a working thing to begin with :

(As usual without JSP code)

Check it, and feed me back if this would be a problematic case in your scenario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;
function initialize()
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9, 72.8);   
    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 11,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);   
    see();
}

    function see()
    {

        var locations = new Array(3); //(<%= count%>);
        for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            locations[i] = new Array(2); //This one is wrong!! (<%= count%>);
        }


    for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    locations[i][0]=18.9 + i/100;
            locations[i][1]=72.8 + i/100; 
    }


                    var i;
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var marker;
                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
                    {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0],locations[i][1]),map: map});

                            var flightPlanCoordinates=[new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0],locations[i][1])];
                            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                                                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                                                                    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                                                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                                                                    strokeWeight: 2
                                                                });
                            flightPath.setMap(map);
                    }


    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width=100%; height:80%"></div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Ya thanks ..... this code is working but when i get the latitude and longitude from database i get northing i mean no overlay is created